# Json parsing Swift not getting print

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, decode

I am new to Swift. I want to fetch some json data from the server using the url. I tried many other solutions but they didn't work. I want to print the `duration` key (text and value) from the array and then print it in console.

The **Json data** is attached below

```
{
    "status": "OK",
    "rows": [
        {
            "elements": [
                {
                    "duration": {
                        "text": "3 hours 49 mins",
                        "value": 13725
                    },
                    "distance": {
                        "text": "225 mi",
                        "value": 361715
                    },
                    "status": "OK"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "origin_addresses": [
        "Washington, DC, USA"
    ],
    "destination_addresses": [
        "New York, NY, USA"
    ]
}
```

**Attached Code**

```
func getdatajson1(){
        
        if let url = URL(string: "http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bQywstyfkO?indent=2") {
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
                if let data = data {
                    do {
                        let res = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
                        print(res.rows)
                    } catch let error {
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
                }.resume()
        }
        
    } 



 struct Root: Codable {
        let rows: [Root2]
    }
    
    
    struct Root2: Codable {
        let elements: [Root3]
    }
    
    struct Root3: Codable {
        let elements: [node]
    }

    
    
    struct node: Codable {
        let duration : [valuesarray]
    
    }
    
    struct valuesarray: Codable {
        let text : String 
        let value : Int
    }
```

Comment: what is printing `res.rows` this statement?

Comment: nothing!! Its the wrong code

Comment: is it printing `nil` or anything else?

Comment: its printing key not found

Comment: "its printing key not found". Then it's printing the ` print(error)`, but please, read that error, or if you don't understand it, add it to your question, it has important information on what went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `duration` is an `Object` and not an `Array`, also change your names and you can use this:

```
struct Root: Decodable {

  let rows: [Rows]

}

struct Rows: Decodable {

 let elements: [Elements]

}

struct Elements: Decodable {

  let duration, distance: LocationValues
}

struct LocationValues: Decodable {
   let text: String
   let value: Int
}

func getdatajson1(){

        if let url = URL(string: "http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bQywstyfkO?indent=2") {
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
                if let data = data {
                    do {
                        let res = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
                        if let row = res.rows.first, let elements = row.elements.first {
                            print(elements.duration.text) //This is how you can get the text value
                            print(elements.distance.text) //This will print the distance
                        }

                    } catch let error {
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
                }.resume()
        }

    }
```

Comment: ``` duration is[Time_String.jsonViewController.Rows(elements: [Time_String.jsonViewController.Elements(duration: Time_String.jsonViewController.LocationValues(text: "3 hours 49 mins", value: 13725), distance: Time_String.jsonViewController.LocationValues(text: "225 mi", value: 361715))])] ``` its printing this but not the exact value of duration text

Comment: To get the value of `duration` you have to fetch values from these. Let me update my answer.

Comment: sure !! Update it

Comment: @DevenNazare Updated.

Comment: Thanks it worked !! Can you please print both Distance and Duration ! will be appreciated

Comment: @DevenNazare Updated my answer, but from now on you have to understand yourself more about this. You can not use `first` everytime, you have understand more about `Decodables`, a quick Google search will help you a lot. Also, if this answer helped mark it as correct so that the future people can rely on this answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your codable struct with the below

```
class Result: Codable {
    var status:String?
    var rows:[Row]?
    var origin_addresses:[String]?
    var destination_addresses:[String]?
}

class Row: Codable {
    var elements:[Element]?
}

class Element: Codable {
    var status:String?
    var duration:Duration?
    var distance:Distance?
}

class Duration: Codable {
    var text:String?
    var value:Int?
}

class Distance: Codable {
    var text:String?
    var value:Int?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should update your `node` model like below

```
struct node: Codable {
     let duration : valuesarray
     let distance : valuesarray
     let status : String
}
```

And you can access your `duration` data from API response like below

```
if let rows = res.rows, rows.count > 0 {

      //Access the element objects from rows
      let arrElements = rows[0].elements, arrElements.count > 0 {

          if let durationData = arrElements[0].duration { //get your duration object
               print(durationData.text)
               print(durationData.value)
          }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

and a hint: go to https://app.quicktype.io/ -> here you can paste your json and you will get your datastructs for free! ;)

```
func getdatajson1(){

            if let url = URL(string: "http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bQywstyfkO?indent=2") {
                URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
                    if let data = data {
                        do {

                            let res = try JSONDecoder().decode(Welcome.self, from: data)
                            print(res.rows)
                        } catch let error {
                            print(error)
                        }
                    }
                }.resume()
            }

        }

        getdatajson1()


       struct Welcome: Codable {
            let status: String
            let rows: [Row]
            let originAddresses, destinationAddresses: [String]

            enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
                case status, rows
                case originAddresses = "origin_addresses"
                case destinationAddresses = "destination_addresses"
            }
        }

        // MARK: - Row
        struct Row: Codable {
            let elements: [Element]
        }

        // MARK: - Element
        struct Element: Codable {
            let duration, distance: Distance
            let status: String
        }

        // MARK: - Distance
        struct Distance: Codable {
            let text: String
            let value: Int
        }
```